# Multiple global shortcuts for the same action

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde-4

In KDE4, I want to be able to change my sound volume both with the built-in Volume Up key as well as <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>.

While I can define alternate keybindings for all program-wide actions, there is no such column  in the Global System Shortcuts settings. How can I define multiple global keyboard shortcuts for the same action?

Comment: I haven't used KDE in a long time, but couldn't you have a shortcut to run a DBUS command to up the volume too?

Comment: Like @supercheetah suggests, I have also gone the DBUS route with a very simple python script to adjust my screen brightness under GNOME 3's fallback mode, since it doesn't offer a screen brightness applet anymore, after GNOME 2.

Answer (score 2):

You might look into a program like AutoKey. https://code.google.com/p/autokey/